# Only one line break in fasta file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a fasta file like:

`grep -A 7 -B 4 COSN229024 wrong.fasta`:

```
>COSN9627597
CGCTGGGCTCGCCTCCAGCCTGGCCTGCATTCCCAAATCTA
>COSN8175610
CAAGAGAGAAATTCTGACACCTCCTAAGTCTACCAAGCTTT
>COSN229024
CACTATAAAAATATTAAGAGA
>COSN18183003
TGTGTTTGTGATTGATGT
>COSN18487588
TGCTTACCCCTTAAATGCAACTTATTTACTTTTACCACTGT
>COSN1681903|COSN1178783
CTTCCCAACTCATGAGTTCTGAATTCCAATACGTCTCCATT
```

I observed that in wrong.fasta approximately half of the sequence of >COSN229024 breaks up and forms a new sequence >COSN18183003. In the end, the whole order of fasta header mess up after breakup. So, I want to put the break part of >COSN229024 back into the >COSN229024 in wrong.fasta and than transfer / replace the header. I used `grep -A 7 -B 4 COSN229024 wrong.fasta`. My desired output would be like this :

```
>COSN9627597
CGCTGGGCTCGCCTCCAGCCTGGCCTGCATTCCCAAATCTA
>COSN8175610
CAAGAGAGAAATTCTGACACCTCCTAAGTCTACCAAGCTTT
>COSN229024
CACTATAAAAATATTAAGAGATGTGTTTGTGATTGATGT
>COSN18183003
TGCTTACCCCTTAAATGCAACTTATTTACTTTTACCACTGT
>COSN18487588
CTTCCCAACTCATGAGTTCTGAATTCCAATACGTCTCCATT
>COSN1681903|COSN1178783
........so on and so forth
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `grep` doesn't rearrange your lines, so if there's a breakup in some lines, it comes from your file, not from `grep`. Maybe try showing the relevant 11 lines from `wrong.fasta`? If it's not a question about `grep` but about joining lines together, you'll have to explain more precisely how lines should be rearranged.

Comment: The way I understand it you want to merge two lines and shift everything below up by one. Does that mean the last two lines in the file don't have `>`? Or the last `>` will go empty?

Comment: @frostschutz: yeah you are right. As after >COSN229024, everything would be shifted below up by one. In the end of new file, I would have > which is empty.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to figure out what produced the broken fasta file and why, then fix that so it doesn't do it again?  i.e. fixing it at the source is better than trying to patch it up later.

Comment: BTW, you can check if it's more than just `COSN229024` that is broken/incomplete.  assuming that all sequence lines are supposed to have 41 characters, try `grep -E -v -B1  '^>|^[CGTA]{41}$' wrong.fasta` - or remove the `$` in the regexp if they're supposed to have at least 41 chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the file using `awk` like this:

```
awk '/^>/{if(x)t=$0;else print"\n"$0} !/^>/{printf"%s",$0;if(t)print"\n"t} /^>COSN229024/{x=1}' < wrong.fasta > good.fasta
```

After this you will probably also need to fix the beginning and the end of the file manually.